# Can't boot from CD/Install Windows

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8

My issue is with Ubuntu 14.04.
I  have recently installed Ubuntu over Windows 8, being unhappy with Windows.
After playing with Ubuntu, I discovered that some of my hardware and software is incompatible with Ubuntu. So, I decided to partition my drive.

I opened GParted, and attempted to shrink my volume, but the maximum size was equal to my minimum size.
I just decided to install Windows. I tried pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> on boot,
but each time, I was greeted with a Terminal screen that showed:
`"[[23~"` while holding down the key.

Ubuntu booted as normal, and I entered the Desktop, but the cursor was missing and I couldn't use my trackpad.
I would like to know how I can shrink my volume, and resolve my problems by booting from a CD.

Thanks!

Comment: First of, GParted should be used when you boot of a live USB; you can't partition hard drive while it's mounted and is in use. Second, windows doesn't like any operating system installed before it. So IMHO, best way would be to boot of live USB, format the hard drive to NTFS format, install Windows, and then install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can't unmount a partition that your using.  If you have to Ubuntu disk, pop that in and boot into the live environment (try Ubuntu without). Then open gparted, and partition your drive yow you want. Then shutdown, and insert your windows 8 install disk.  Make sure you click the customize option, and choose to install it to the correct partition.  When that's all done, you should have windows 8 installed alongside Ubuntu.

Next you need to either A: add an Ubuntu option in the windows boot loader, or B: reinstall grub to be able to boot and into both oses.

They should add a multibooting forum for this stuff + boot loader stuff.